# In a group $G$, if for all $a,b,c\in G$, $ab=ca\Rightarrow b=c$, then $G$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. If for all $a,b,c\in G$, $ab=ca\Rightarrow b=c$, then phow can I prove that  $G$ is abelian?

Comment: @mesel That doesn't work. We have $ab=ba \implies b=b$, but not vice versa.

Comment: $ab=aba^{-1}a\implies aba^{-1}=b \implies ab=ba$. you are right @wythagoras.

Answer (score 11):

Let $a,b \in G$ arbitrary and set $c := aba^{-1}$. Then $$ca = ab$$ and your hypothesis implies $c = b$. So for arbitrary $a,b \in G$ you have $$b = aba^{-1}$$ hence $G$ is an abelian group.

Comment: As a general note,  what Holonomia did here was use the action called "conjugation" on $b$ by $a$,  and another way of saying a group is abelian is that conjugation fixes every element

Answer (score 2):

Check your hypothesis for b=xy, c=yx and a=y

Answer (score 1):

Another Way,

Consider arbitrary a,b ∈ G

```
     ab  = ab           (now post-multiply by a)
   (ab)a = (ab)a        (now use associativity)
   a(ba) = (ab)a        (by given hypothesis)
     ba  = ab
```

Since for arbitrary a,b ab=ba, G is abelian.